# How do I check if ringtone pointed by uri exists?

Tags: java, android, uri, ringtone

I'm able to play a ringtone using the following code

```
rone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this.getContext(), Uri.parse(one));
rone.play();
```

How do I check if the audio file pointed by uri exists? When the user deletes a file from their phone, I'm not able to play the ringtone and it crashes.

Comment: check whether the rone is null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getRingtone()` will return null if the ringtone does not exist.

Always check that a returned value is not null, this is a good practice whenever you call methods that might return null value. This will prevent a whole lot of `NullPointerException`

Comment: Thanks, I was able to check if the ringtone exists by checking if (ringtone!=null){
//do something
}else{
//no ringtone, do something else
}

Comment: For some reason, I get a non-null object even though I've deleted its file in the ".../notifications" folder, and I also got a weird name for the ringtone (a number) instead of the original name.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `getRingtonePosition()` method instead of `getRingtone()`:

```
final RingtoneManager rm = new RingtoneManager(preference.getContext());
final Uri loadedRingtoneUri = Uri.parse(ringtoneUriString);
final int pos = rm.getRingtonePosition(loadedRingtoneUri);

// if loaded ringtone uri is valid, use it or use default
final Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(preference.getContext(),
                        (pos != -1) ? loadedRingtoneUri :
                                      Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
```

Comment: I'm getting a -1 even when the URI is a valid one and points to an existing file.

Comment: Ah, I know why.  You need this additional line after instantiating a `RingtoneManager`: `rm.setType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);`  OR pick whichever ringtone type your application is using.  Ringtone manager needs to know what type of ringtones to load (use `TYPE_ALL` for all types).